# Weight Paint and deforming issue

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, parent

I seem to be having a problem with my rig. I've added Automatic Weights to my mesh, but for some reason, whenever I rotate or move the thigh or control root, the legs deform and split away from the torso. I'm not sure why this is happening. All my armature is parented correctly and the torso and legs are joined together via Ctrl + J. I even tried parenting them. Any ideas?

Here's my save:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everyone has his own way to rig, personally I would organize the armature this way: switch the direction of your hips bone and parent the thigh and the spine to it. Also, you will need to enable the *Deform* option of this bone. And, at last, you will have to switch to *Weight Paint* mode to make a lot of corrections, because it's currently not well weight painted: Keep your armature in *Pose* mode, then select your mesh and switch it to *Weight Paint* mode, then select each bone to see and correct its influence.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I did all that, though I'm having difficulty getting to grips with Weight Painting. I'm never sure how much or little is enough; it never seems to make much difference to the deforming. I've also noticed that if I right click on one of the green bones, the mesh goes purple. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I can't tell you what purple mesh means, I don't know, just don't pay attention and paint what is supposed to be paint, also, don't forget to disable the Limit Selection to Visible button on the horizontal menu bar, so that when you paint it also affects the other side of the character

Comment: Thanks for the tip about Limit Selection to Visible. :)

Can't for the life of me figure this issue out though. It doesn't matter if I make the waist area completely blue either, it still deforms and detaches. :-\

Comment: If you do what I said it should work. Also, keep your armature in Pose mode, then select your mesh and switch it to Weight Paint mode, then select each bone to see and correct its influence (use the Blend > Mix and Substract options of the brush).

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested a few times, but I just can't get it. :( The waist and torso either split away or they deform badly and stretch out like melted cheese. You'll have to show me what areas you've added Weight Textures to and how much.

Comment: in that case please share your current version

Comment: I'll have to make another. I don't really have one as I've been restarting and trying from scratch whilst practising. Also, because my character is made of multiple objects, is it a good idea to join them altogether? Or doesn't it matter in this case?

Comment: yes of course, it's better to join the different meshes to make one object

Comment: Okay. There really isn't any attempt I can show you, I'm afraid. I'm just going round in circles - restarting, attempting it, messing up, restarting, repeat. :(

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere... Also, it looks to me that when the mesh turns purple it's because no Weight Paint has been assigned to that object or vertices.

The deformation seems to have lessened thanks to selecting one group of armature (green on the torso) and then parenting them to the torso object. I've done that with all of them for each group and object instead of everything together. Applying what you suggested helps too. Now, though, I'm getting the same issue with the spine - it detaches from the legs. :-\

Comment: Fixed. Looks like the spine bone wasn't connected to the chest bone. :)